# Clean JSON objects in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was given a task to reformat 100 million JSON objects in Spark. Example of the Input JSON object.

```
{
  name: 123,
  schools: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      deleted: 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      deleted: 0,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Excepted output:

```
{
  name: 123,
  schools: [
    {
      Id: 2,
      deleted: 0,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Remove schools w/ deleted 1. Is it possible to do this in Spark? I am pretty new to it, any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you done? Have you tried to read that json? What step did you struggle to do this?

Comment: Why both Id is 1?? Just remove every member in array with `deleted: 1`?

Answer (score 2):

I would like you to read about spark [transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

your task can be done easily using spark.
if you are using scala lang then create a [case class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) which defines your input schema.
or if you are using java lang then create a [DTO](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) which is serializable.

scala abstract code :

```
 case class Data( // define schema fields here)
   
   import spark.implicits._
   val inputDF = spark.read.json(inputFile).as[Data]
   val finalDF = inputDF.map(data => {
      data.schools = data.schools.filter(x => !x.deleted)
      data
      //or you can create new object and update school object in ti
   })
   finalDF.write.json(oploc)
```

read about spark encoders as well if you have nested objects because we need to tell spark explicitly how to encode and decode such kind of complex objects.